# In unit testing, how to Assert if result is Guid?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, assert

I am working on unit testing using visual studio unit test framework

In my unit test method, I want to assert if the result is a Guid like

`3C99A192-9844-4174-AC32-91976A5F2CBF`.

Currently, I have come up with this. But I am sure there will be a better way to handle this.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateAppointment_Should_Return_Guid()
{
  string result = CreateAppointment();
  Guid guidResult;
  if (Guid.TryParse(result.GuestId, guidResult))
  {
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
  }
  else
  {
    Assert.IsTrue(false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Why not shorter one? `TryParse` returns bool.

```
Guid guidResult;
Assert.IsTrue(Guid.TryParse(result.GuestId, out guidResult));
```

your idea seems to be legit. You are checking if string parses to guid, so you can tell if string is valid guid.

Comment: this is good.. I will mark this as answer, if I don't get some other way from the community

Comment: This can be cut down to one line in newer C# versions by defining the output type in the method call: 
`Assert.IsTrue(Guid.TryParse(result.GuestId, out Guid guidResult))`

Comment: @Anthony yep, now it can, but back in 2014 it couldn't :)

Answer (score 2):

This might help:
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(CreateAppointment(), typeof(Guid));